# Ideal viewport size for mobile phone websites

Tags: css, mobile, web, media-queries, mobile-website

I'm wondering which should be the ideal `viewport` size to design mobile websites.

Designing a site with `320px` width will speed up a lot the site in terms of images loading (as their size will be smaller), and, if just adjusting the viewport to be `320px` makes it look full width, then, why should we design websites in a higher `width` ?

- What is the disadvantage of designing a mobile website in 320px width?
- Which would you say is the ideal `viewport` size for a mobile website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The web is inherently flexible. Embrace the medium, don't impose a false limitation because it seems easier at first.
2. What do you define as 'mobile'? Will that change in 6 or 12 months?
3. There are more devices than the iPhone. Flexible sites just work* on almost every device *including* the iPhone.

There many eloquent and well-informed opinions on the subject:

- http://alistapart.com/article/dao
- http://blog.andyhume.net/responsive-by-default/
- http://adactio.com/journal/6120/
- http://futurefriend.ly/

There's no harm in ruling that all images created for the site are of a specified size, although scaling and resampling them to fit their allotted container is relatively heavy work. As with anything online within the browser - a medium designed to compromise - it's a balance.

Comment: Using a `viewport` there's no need for responsive design. It will force all devices to see it at that fixed width. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @Alvaro providing the browser supports it. However on a very large screen (such as a Google Nexus 10) being stretched is likely to provide a poor experience and conversely on small feature phone the forced 'zoomed-out' experience is likely to be unreadable.

Comment: The website I'm working is different from desktop and tablet than for phone devices. The desktop and tablets version is already finished and therefore I can not start from scratch doing a responsive design. As all popular phones (android, apple...) support the `viewport` feature, I guess I will keep on using it.